# How space between . and property name works?

Tags: objective-c

I made an accidental mistake and found it is still working. I recreated it simply over the view here to demonstrate. Ignore the property i used and value i am assigning.

```
self.view. frame = CGRectZero;
self.view. tag = 23;

NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame));
NSLog(@"%i",self.view.tag);
```

How compiler sees this and ok with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in C and Objective-C, whitespace between tokens doesn't matter. When parsing the source text, the compiler calls the [lexer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) repeatedly (and [builds an abstract data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) to represent the source code). The lexer function is only interested in non-whitespace tokens (there are some deviances, but this observation tends to be true in general), and however you organize your code,

```
object.member
```

and

```
object .member
```

and

```
object. member
```

and

```
object . member
```

will all be recognized as the very same sequence of tokens: `<ident> <memberof> <ident>`.

Comment: HOw you type that much in few seconds :)

Comment: @AnoopVaidya C'mon, it was a whole minute :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer and those links.